# How can I prepend to an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

What is the best way to prepend to an array in Ruby. Perhaps something similar to Python's `list.insert(0, 'foo')`?

I'd like to be able to add an element to a Ruby array at the 0 position and have all other elements shifted along.

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb: do you downvote every question that might be a duplicate ? just inform the asker

Comment: No.  I downvoted because the question shows poor research effort

Comment: then why not inform him but sanction right away not knowing what causes it

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
array = ['b', 'c']

array.unshift('a')

p array
=> ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

As Scott G has pointed out in the comments, as of Ruby 2.5.0 `#prepend` has been added as an alias for `#unshift`.

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-unshift

Comment: I think it should be mentioned that as of ruby `2.5.0` the method `prepend` has been added as an alias for `unshift`. I'd personally prefer to use `prepend` in my code to improve readability as it's more common nomenclature and still plenty accurate to describe what's happening from a technical perspective.

Comment: I personally prefer `unshift` over `prepend` for 1) symmetry with `shift` and 2) funny mnemonic (to remember which of `shift` and `unshift` does what, remove the letter "f" from the names).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I use the same mnemonic!  Maybe I learned it from you years ago. :)

Comment: @SteveTurczyn: haha, that's possible :)

Answer (score 6):

Another way than Steve's answer

```
array = ['b', 'c']
array = ['a'] + array #["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: For completeness: there is one difference between those two answers. This one will create a new array, while Steve's will modify the existing array. It might be a huge difference if it is referenced by more than one variable.

Comment: you are right but in most cases it won't matter and it is more readable

Answer (score 5):

```
array = ["b", "c"]
array.insert(0, "a", "a") # => ["a", "a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: This raises an `ArgumentError`, you probably meant `insert(0, "a", "a")`.

Comment: Furthermore you can splat an array to prepend it this way. Thus `other_array = ['a', 'a']; array.insert(0, *other_array)` has the same effect.